# jquery: Unable to have the click event fire on image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

I have a javascript code that have span tag and inside the span tag there is an image tag and normal text next to the image tag. I want to bind the click event on image tag but the event didn't fire at all. I use the jquery to accomplish this.

```
var a = new Image();
$(a).prop('src','blah');
$(a).load( blah);


$(span).append($(a));
$(a).click(function (e) { alert('asdf'); } );
```

not event if i do this

```
$(span).find($(a)).click( blah );


 var button = $(this.imgClose).clone();
        $(button).prop('id', 'close');
        $(template).append($(button));

        $(template).find('#close').on('click', '', function (event) { alert('sss'); });
```

Comment: Hiya @AndrewWhitaker if you will set it as answer I will upvote you bruv, cheers!

Comment: Thank to you all.. it's finally working ... I don't know why I add the event after the line :  var value = $(template).html() + text;
            $(template).html(value);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this since you are appending the `a` and then trying to click

Rest you can see @gdoron 's & @Andrew stuff above as well

**API** reside here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Also prop vs attr : [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

hope this helps,

**code**

```
$('a').on('click', function(){ 
   alert('HULK');
});
```

Comment: i use on as well but still no effect. But if I add the image tag outside of a span tag it clickable

Comment: Hey @Simon try this `$('span').siblings('a').click(function() {..`  (API: http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) **OR** flick me your code in jsfiddle I will help you out bruv, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(span).append($(a));
```

Should be:

```
$('span').append($(a));
```

**[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TU2St/)**

Comment: I assume `span` is meant to be a variable containing the `<span>` element.

Comment: yea is a variable sorry it's my mistake

Comment: @Simon. O.K. But as you can see in the DEMO, IT WORKS!